# What is the average size of a DateTimeOffset on a x64 bit Azure machine?

Tags: c#, memory, marshalling, sizeof, datetimeoffset

I've been trying to get the size of a [`DateTimeOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx) struct in my code so that I can compute the size of a parent object.   The problem is that neither the [**`sizeof`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx) operator nor the [`Marshal.SizeOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s4920fa(v=vs.110).aspx) function work for this purpose.

sizeof won't work because I have to compile with the unsafe flag, and this feature isn't enough of a justification to do that.   Marshal.SizeOf throws an exception:

> Type 'System.DateTimeOffset' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged
>   structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed.

I've given up on trying to calculate the size of a struct like this, because every line of attack/blog post comes up with one error or another.

Can someone just tell me what the average size of a DateTimeOffset is on a 64 bit Azure web server is?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The accepted answer is not correct, it ignores alignment.  The size of a struct is not simply the sum of its members.  Extra space between fields as well as the end of the struct may be required to help the processor to read the field efficiently and implement the atomicity guarantees provided by the .NET memory model.

It is extra convoluted for DateTimeOffset, the Microsoft programmer that wrote the DateTimeOffset struct made a big mistake by starting to code by copy/pasting the DateTime struct.  Which has a historical mistake that matters a great deal for DateTimeOffset since it has two fields instead of one.  It uses LayoutKind.Auto instead of Sequential.  Easily visible in the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetimeoffset.cs,36)

That gives the CLR leeway to arrange the fields to be optimal in the whatever mode it is running in.  In 32-bit mode it will *not* align an Int64 to 8 bytes, like it normally does, but to 4 bytes.  That puts less padding between the fields, the size is 12 bytes.

Likewise, in 64-bit mode it likes to align fields to 8.  That produces more padding between the fields.

The only good way to see this is by using the debugger.  Run this bit of code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var arr = new DateTimeOffset[] {
            new DateTimeOffset(0x123456789abcdef0, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)),
            new DateTimeOffset(0x123456789abcdef0, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)),
        };
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
    }
```

When the breakpoint hits, use Debug > Windows > Memory > Memory1 and type `&arr[0]` in the Address box to look at the array content.  You'll see something similar to:

```
0x00000115DC4FBA30  3c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 76 f8 38 70 56 34 12  <.......ðvø8pV4.
0x00000115DC4FBA40  3c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f0 76 f8 38 70 56 34 12  <.......ðvø8pV4.
0x00000115DC4FBA50  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
```

You can easily see the Offset field (60 = 0x003c) and the DateTime field.  I resized the window make the 2 elements obvious, it isn't going to look quite so clean on your machine :)  But just count the bytes off until they repeat, DateTimeOffset takes **16 bytes** in 64-bit mode.

The fact that the size is different between 32-bit and 64-bit mode should in general worry you a good deal.  This bug otherwise never needed to be fixed, there is no reasonable interop story for DateTimeOffset, it never matches an equivalent unmanaged type.  It is the designated interop type in WinRT (aka UWP) but the language projection built into the CLR hides the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is not completely reliable (and assumes array overhead is constant, which is probably true under sane conditions), but below is a simple way to answer this question empirically.  If for some reason you wish to test on an environment which lacks a debugger, this approach might be good for a sanity check:

```
void Main()
{
    PrintSize<DateTimeOffset>();
}

public static void PrintSize<T>() 
{
    GC.Collect();
    long gc1 = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
    const int sz = 100000;
    T[] foo = new T[sz];
    long gc2 = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
    GC.KeepAlive(foo);
    Console.WriteLine($"{(gc2 - gc1) / (double)sz} bytes per {typeof(T)}");
}
```

When I tested as 32 bit, it printed 12 (+/- 0.001).
When I tested as 64 bit, it printed 16 (+/- 0.001).

Note that this sort of test is best done as a standalone application; a more complex application is more likely to have unpredictable changes in RAM usage.

Comment: +1 Thanks for solving my original issue.  I was thinking of doing this in my web app, but I couldn't guarantee it was thread safe, since multiple requests could be occurring.

Comment: To an extent you can reduce this trick's sensitivity to other influences by increasing sz.  However, this code temporarily burns up a chunk of memory, so it's not ideal for production use.  However, you could just spin up a new Azure instance, run the code, then drop the instance.  Anyhow, Hans's approach is way better when you need trustworthy, precise numbers.  However, this is the approach I tend to use when I want to guesstimate the memory impact of a new application feature (mostly to sanity check order-of-magnitude memory consumption predictions).

Answer (score 0):

It occupies 10 bytes.

Looking at the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetimeoffset.cs,53), it has an `Int16` and a `DateTime`; `DateTime` has a single `UInt64`.

I have no idea why `Marshal.SizeOf` can't measure it.